# Microsoft Sync framework Architecture Conflict

Tags: azure, microsoft-sync-framework

I have developed an application using Microsft Sync framework 2.1, It works fine on my local system which is a 32bit windows 8 PC. However when I deployed the Server side of the project to azure (which is a 64bit platform) I get the popular "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID `{EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011}` failed due to the following error:

**80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"**
 which usually means there is a conflict in the system architecture and the Sync library refrenced.

My direct question is, Must the client and server both be on the same architecture for Sync framework to work i.e can we have server on 64bit and client on 32 bit

Comment: Are you sure you registered your com class?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h627s4zy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you're deploying two tier, the client and server platform do not need to match. but the build target for your app must match the platform for the Sync Fx you installed.

e.g., If the target platform of your app (check your Project properties in VS), is x86, then you should have x86 Sync Fx installed